# Fix ear cup foam and leather

Tags: headphones

I have Steelseries Prism Elite headset 
Any idea how to fix ear cups fake leather, its slowly going to loose?

Hard to explain, heres  to images how it should be and hows it now. Both ear cups are having same issue.

I have been thinking just to rip partially foam off, put some glue and then the leather.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6scb.jpg <-- images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way the cover edge is cut (in VVVVV shape), shows is not glued into the cup—it's a "press-fit" which means it is held in place between two plastic pieces inside the cup by pressure. There's no glue normally used for assembly.

I see *NO* trace of glue in your photos (which are ***very*** good, by the way).

The problem appears to be due to a fault in manufacturing. I think you have a "*lemon*."

They should be replaced by the manufacturer *for free*. When you return the set, tell them they "came apart." This is not an uncommon problem.

Otherwise they look in great condition which strengthens my opinion. There is no sign of mis-use or abuse.

**Important:** Find out *before* you attempt to repair them or the manufacturer could deny responsibility.

Comment: Detail: If all of the points of the VVVVs are not inside the ring that holds the cover to the cup, the ring will be loose. Gradually, the rest of the cover will work loose as it has with your pair. This appears to be the issue.